# paste names that are assigned to a plot object in R

Tags: r, plot, grid, paste

I have written a function that generates multiples plots where the number of plots is decided by the algorithm.  At the end of this function I want to use plot_grid from cowplot package to make a grid of all plots. So, for the simplified example if there is 5 plots in a grid, I have the following three lines of codes (simplified) and showing the two outputs I get:

```
> gnum=5
> plot_grid(noquote(paste0("pl", 1:gnum, collapse = ",")), nrow = gnum)
Warning message:
In as_grob.default(plot) :
  Cannot convert object of class noquote into a grob.
> plot_grid(cat(noquote(paste0("pl", 1:gnum, collapse = ","))), nrow = gnum)
pl1,pl2,pl3,pl4,pl5
```

None of the above produced the plot grid.

I cannot pass the term

```
paste0("pl", 1:gnum, collapse = ",")
```

to the plot_grid function

Just to test the function, if I write the following code (pl1, pl2, etc are plot objects created by the previous code), I will get the plot grid as I want:

```
     plot_grid(pl1, pl2, pl3, pl4, pl5, nrow=5)
```

But obviously I want to paste the plot objects "pl1, pl2, pl3,..." into the plot-grid function because the number of plots is data driven.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
do.call(plot_grid, c(mget(paste0("pl", 1:gnum)), nrow=gnum))
```

Example:

```r
library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)

gnum <- 2
pl1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_point()
pl2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_line()
do.call(cowplot::plot_grid, c(mget(paste0("pl", 1:gnum)), nrow=gnum))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One approach can utilise `eval` and `parse`:

```
eval(parse(text=paste0('plot_grid(',paste0("pl", 1:gnum, collapse = ","),', nrow = ',gnum,')')))
```